# Devise re-directing continuously when it should not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The following behaviour is observed in testing controller actions; they are boilerplate actions from a new application, where authorization will gradually be built into.

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
```

The tests (using Minitest) return unexpected results (shown inline)

```
require "test_helper"

class ContactsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  setup do
    @contact = contacts(:one)
    @admin = users(:admin)
    @one = users(:one)
    @two = users(:two)
  end

  test "blank slate" do
    get new_contact_url
    assert_response :success
  end
=> 1 assertions

  test "should get new" do
    sign_in @admin
    get new_contact_url
    assert_response :success
  end
=>  was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>

  test "fail test just to see what happens" do
    sign_in @one
    get new_contact_url
    assert_redirected_to root_path
  end
=> Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>.
```

when `before_action :authenticate_user!` is added at top of controller, the first test fails with:

```
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>
```

and the latter two fail with the same result as previously.

The test helper is bare bones.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  fixtures :all

end
```

`rails generate devise:controllers` was run but all actionable lines are commented out.  The only basic difference is that the `application_controller.rb` has

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name_last, :name_first, :public_persona]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end
```

There are no references to `redirect_to new_user_session_path` anywhere in the code.

```
Ruby 3.1.2
Rails 7.0.4
Devise 4.8.1
```

Why is devise consistently re-directing to new_user_session_path on authentication?

Comment: Make sure this line is present in spec/rails_helper.rb. 
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request

Comment: do you have a documentation reference for that?

Comment: Here is the link. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request)#1-simple-approach

Comment: Also share your spec/spec_helper.rb (or spec/rails_helper.rb) flie configs in the question

Comment: the `test_helper`  is there - using Minitest.

Comment: Protip - add `before_action :authenticate_user!` to your ApplicationController. You then opt out of authention by using `skip_before_action  :authenticate_user!`. This is secure by default and won't leave security holes just because you forgot to add authorization somewhere.